# warn:walrus url not configured in eucalyptus centos 6

Tags: centos6, eucalyptus, walrus

I am installing eucalyptus on centos 6 and while generating administrator credentials on the cloud controller
 I am getting the

warning:Walrus url not configured

on running the following commands:

1.
Generate administrator credentials.
/usr/sbin/euca_conf --get-credentials admin.zipunzip admin.zip

2.
Source the eucarc file.
source eucarc

How to remove the error?

Answer (score 0):

It generally means, Walrus is not registered properly or not registered at all.
Also, it looks like you may be using an old version of Eucalyptus, I would recommend to try a newer release of Eucalyptus if it's a fresh installation.